# How to update mailbox properties of exchange online by scripting?

Tags: exchange-server, office365

How to use script/power shell to update these properties of Office 365 mailbox, such as street, city, state, zipcode, workphone, office, webpage etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set-User to do that see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998221%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Cheers
Glen